# Rails/ Devise - How to Create a User and a Post Through the Same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've got a Devise model called user.

I've also got a model called projects.

I want the user to create a project when they create their user account. I've got the functionality working; however, the users project isn't saving to the database.

Here's projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = current_user.projects
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thanks! Your project has been saved. Please check your email inbox now.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:service, :location, :details, :email)
    end
end
```

and user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank}, allow_destroy: true
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
end
```

and the Project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and the form for creating users / their first post

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |u|

  = devise_error_messages!

  = u.fields_for :project do |p|
    .field = p.text_field :service, placeholder: "What service do you need?"
    .field = p.text_field :location, placeholder: "What's the project location?"


  .field = u.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "What's your email address?"

  .actions = u.submit "Click to continue"
```

Any ideas as to how I can get my Projects index view to show only the posts that belong to the current user?

Comment: Where's the part where you are trying to create user account? and how is the posts controller related to your question, you mentioned user, user account and projects not posts?

Comment: typo - post should have been project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your user model has_many projects you'll need to modify the form to be

```
 = u.fields_for :projects do |p|
   .field = p.text_field :service, placeholder: "What service do you need?"
   .field = p.text_field :location, placeholder: "What's the project location?"
```

And add in your application controller add `projects_attributes` to the user's permitted parameters, use a block for that

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(projects_attributes: [:service, :location])
    end
  end
```

For more info check

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7b33a8ef5749e0b593d785a1cd4787d2979cdee5/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb

Comment: I get the following error with that code: `private method permit called for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007fcdf2f96100>`

Comment: I update the answer (following: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating your post, you aren't passing in a user. You can either pass in a user before you save:

```
@project = Project.new(params[:project])
@project.user = current_user
```

or you can create the post based on the relation:

```
@project = current_user.posts.new(params[:project])
```

Comment: added @project.user = current_user ...but the data is still not persisting/being displayed in the projects index view

Comment: In rails console, what do you get when you run `Post.last.user`?

Comment: ran Project.last.user (there is no post model) and it returned nil

Comment: ok, your form is actually posting to the registration controller, not to the projects controller. I don't think my answer is going to help you.

The way you're trying to do this, you'll likely need to override the default devise controller, and change your routes to match.

There is more info in the devise readme under [Configuring Controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)

Comment: that is correct - I'm over-riding the default devise registrations controller to accept project attributes and create a project when a user completes their registration.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect from your question you haven't configured the user creation to allow your nested project parameters. You seem to be focussing on the `Project` controller and code but your user will be created by `Devise::RegistrationsController` (unless you've specified your own version).

You need to tell devise what parameters you'll allow for a user create (see [Devise Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters))

You probably need something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [project_attributes: [:service, :location]])
  end
end
```

Or [for devise 3](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/3-stable#strong-parameters):

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << { project_attributes: [:service, :location] }
end
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when trying that code: `private method permit called for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007fa2f3d01bd0>`

Comment: I've added a bit that should work for devise 3 (and a link to relevant docs)

Comment: Tried adding that however the project data is still not getting saved and I'm getting this error in my logs: `Unpermitted parameter: project`

Comment: You probably need just `project:` instead of `project_attributes:` then.

Comment: still getting the same error after changing to project:

Comment: Okay, I give up then. Hard to diagnose with just a browser in front of me but I think that the general problem is that you need to get the project attributes accepted as part of your user sign up. Maybe a root around those docs would help or maybe further questioning. Not sure I'm going to get you any further in the scope of this question/comment chain though I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks for trying - I'll let you know when I come up with a solution